# Getting current location in google map and pass it to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to display a direction in google map from current location to a known location. my code is shown below:

```
      <script>
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var bne = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.572832, 153.065247);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:7,
    center: bne
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}


function calcRoute() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function (pos) {
      var start = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitiude,
                                         pos.coords.longitude);

      var end = 'sunnybank,brisbane';
      var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      });
    }, 
    function (err) {
      alert('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
    });
  }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

It seems that navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() doesn't work for me, is there other ways to retrieve current location and pass it to start variable?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: google chrome..does it matters?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition), the getCurrentPosition function passes a [Position object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Position) to its callback function (it is asynchronous so can't return anything), which is not a google.maps.LatLng object (but contains the information required to create one).

```
function calcRoute() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitiude,
                                       pos.coords.longitude);

    var end = 'sunnybank,brisbane';
    var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else alert("Directions request failed: "+status);
    });
  }, function(err) {
    alert('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/yLue3z27/)

Comment: Thx, I have changed my codes based on your suggestion~the browser prompt me for allowing get location. But after the route was not displayed. I used F12 and also nothing indicated, any idea why?

Comment: Perhaps the status returned by the directions service was not "OK", I usually put in the alert that I just added to my answer to let me know when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

There could be 3 reasons:

1. Your browser doesn't support geolocation.
2. You have disabled geolocation tracking. In google chrome you can enable it looking in options, searching location in your settings.
3. If you are working on a HTML file on your pc directly as file:/// geolocation is disabled for security reasons.