# Get Google Directions inside HTML from Current Location

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geocoding

I have implemented the Google Directions Services code into my HTML and changed the select tags to suit my needs and all is working fine.

I was wondering if it were possible to have one of the Drop Down Options set to "My Current Location" which would then allow me to show directions to somewhere from my current location.

Everytime I choose the "My Current Location" Option, the folloing error occurs:

```
Directions request failed due to NOT_FOUND
```

HTML Select Box Code:

```
<b>Start: </b>
    <select id="start">
      <option value="Current Location">My Current Location</option>
      <option value="New York">New York</option>
      <option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>
      <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
    </select>
    <b>End: </b>
    <select id="end">
      <option value="New York">New York</option>
      <option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>
      <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
    </select>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
<script>

      function initMap() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('buildingMap'), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var onChangeHandler = function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
        document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
        document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
          origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
          destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Is your page served over https:?

Comment: It is through `localhost` for now, it is only a project.

Comment: You will need to serve it over https: and use `.getCurrentPosition` to get the current location.  Related question: [Getting current location in google map and pass it to a variable in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966939/getting-current-location-in-google-map-and-pass-it-to-a-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: I have tested the getCurrentPosition earlier, and it still works on `localhost` because I still have an internet connection. 
How would i imolement it into the javasvript above though...