# How to pull user's current location and display on google map api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So two things I am trying to accomplish
1) to pull the user's current location
2) then to display it on a google map

from my research, I see that I can use the following to get the user's currention location

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
};
```

and the following to initiate a google map

```
function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
```

so the problem I am having is how can I accomplish both at the same time?
I have tried to put the second function inside the first function, but that doesn't work ... 
thank you all for your help in advance !

Comment: related question: [Getting current location in google map and pass it to a variable in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966939/getting-current-location-in-google-map-and-pass-it-to-a-variable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

initMap needs to know what the location is.  Currently, you're setting the position to "uluru" inside initMap; instead, try passing the coordinates into the function, and then pulling the coordinates off of that object (you could just reuse the object, but you'd have to account for the fact that the fields are called `longitude`/`latitude` in the first case and `lng`/`lat` on the second).  Something like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
  initMap(crd);
};

function initMap(coordinates) {
    var location = {'lng': coordinates.longitude, 'lat': coordinates.latitude};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: location
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I got it to work now :)